# Convert nd array to key, value dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a function in python to convert an nd-array into a dictionary where key is a tuple of index and value is the matrix value at that index?

For example:

```
A = np.random.random([3,4,5])
```

Result:

```
{(i,j,k): A[i,j,k]}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sure: you can use `np.ndenumerate` to accomplish this:

```
{ index: v for index, v in np.ndenumerate(A) }
```

Or simply, as DSM pointed out:

```
dict(np.ndenumerate(A))
```

Comment: Or just `dict(np.ndenumerate(A))`; since we're not changing anything the dictcomp doesn't really help us.

Comment: Is there a way you can convert this back to an nd array?

Comment: @user2796123 I would suggest asking a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the answer from brianpck is the keys will look like:

```
  (0,): 1531.827559532321,
  (1,): 1580.8390773018477,
  (2,): 1651.6454305202753,
  (3,): 1570.272671819512,
```

if you want keys like:

```py
  0: 1531.827559532321,
  1: 1580.8390773018477,
  2: 1651.6454305202753,
  3: 1570.272671819512,
```

Just use this:

```
{ index[0]: v for index, v in np.ndenumerate(A) }
```

P.S: be careful if your dimensions are more than 1 for the np array.