# How to convert a float object to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, sparse-matrix

> "sampling_strategy" can be a float only when the type of target is binary. For multi-class, use a dict.

this is the error when i am using SMOTE.

```
sm = SMOTE(random_state=2, ratio=1.0)
X_train_res, y_train_res = sm.fit_sample(x,y)
```

my x is as follows:

```
(3, 0) 2 
(4, 0) 1 
(5, 0) 3 
(8, 0) 2 
(9, 0) 1 
(11, 0) 1 
(12, 0) 2 
(15, 0) 7 
(19, 0) 28
# so .. on
```

shape is (2988, 30000) and y is also similar.

I want my float values in a dictionary, so that i can apply SMOTE on that as it is a multi-class i need that in a dictionary.

Comment: SMOTE? either way can you explicitly state what you want the dictionary to look like e.g `{3:0, 4:0, ...}`

Comment: i want it to look like {(3, 0): 2,
 (4, 0): 1,
 (5, 0): 3,
 (8, 0): 2,
 (9, 0): 1,
 (11, 0): 1,
 (12, 0): 2}

Comment: what is x, a list? if so, what are the elements such as "(3, 0) 2". Is the a string? or tuple and...

Comment: x is <class 'scipy.sparse.coo.coo_matrix'> and its float 
and y is <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: `todok()` from the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html) looks like it may potentially do what you're asking

Comment: ya, todok worked for sparse matrix, but for numpy.ndarray iam not able to convert to dict.

Comment: There's a few similar posts on stackoverflow. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43811743/convert-nd-array-to-key-value-dictionary) looks like what you'll need

Comment: both todok() for sparse matrix and dict(np.ndenumerate(A)) for array worked to convers to dict, but still when i run the SMOTE it gives an error "ValueError: Expected array-like (array or non-string sequence)"